# Force IMPORTRANGE to update at certain intervals

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I saw several complains about the delay of updating data through IMPORTRANGE in Google Sheets but I need the opposite and don't want the second sheet to get updated automatically, just update at the end of the day for example.

The code is already like this:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("The Key","The_Page!B:D")
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to use the script editor and write a simple function of the kind:

```
function importData()
{

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //source ss

var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("The_Page");      //opens the sheet with your source data

var values = sheet.getRange("B:D").getValues();   //gets needed values

var ts = SpreadsheetApp.openById("The Key");    //target ss - paste your key

ts.getSheetByName("Name of the target sheet").getRange("B:D").setValues(values);

}
```

And then add a time-driven trigger to this project (Resources > Current project's triggers > Add a new one).

Answer (score 2):

I hacked around this by, on both spreadsheets by creating a refresh loop using a `NOW` cell, with both spreadsheets crossreferencing each other's `NOW` cell.

When the original sheet gets appended with a form submission or something, it updates its own `NOW` cell, and reupdates own `IMPORTRANGE` cell. The second spreadsheet follows suit, updating its own `NOW` cell to provide the original sheet with the correct data. Because the second spreadsheet has updated itself, it also updates the main `IMPORTRANGE` which refreshes the data you want it to display in the first place, as well as the `IMPORTRANGE` cell which gets the `NOW` cell from the original spreadsheet

At least, I'm pretty sure that's how it works. All I know, and all I care about, frankly, is that it works