# Import data from many different spreadsheets (slow)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a formula with dozens of importrange, from as many different spreadsheets. It, of course, slows the spreadsheet, makes my main spreadsheet update everytime there is a modification in one of the spreadsheets...

I'd like my IMPORTRANGE formulas to refresh once every 24h instead of each time there is a modification. It seems like importrange doesn't allow that, so I'm looking for something similar (a script, i suppose). I found this: [Force IMPORTRANGE to update at certain intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24336011/force-importrange-to-update-at-certain-intervals)
(I know I would have to modify it a bit since this script *exports the data to another spreadsheet* and I'd like to *import from an another spreadsheet* but that should be doable)

I haven't tested this script, but before trying i have a couple questions:

1. Is there a simpler solution, maybe a formula that doesn't require a script? Or a function that i don't know about...
2. If a script is required, is this kind of script (in the link above) really the efficient way to go? I would have to modify this script to be able to import from dozens of different spreadsheets.I'm wondering how slow the import process will be, since the script will have dozens, hundreds of imports to do each night (with maybe 5000 cells in each import) ? If it's a matter of minutes, no problem, but if it means hours, not so much.

---

**Context:**  
I run an event agency. For each prospect, we duplicate a "client" template spreadsheet.
When the prospect confirms and becomes a client, we paste the url of the "client" spreadsheet in a master spreadsheet (one line = one client = one url = one importrange in my main formula)

Thanks to some importrange formulas and queries, we can centralize on that file in the master file the necessary information from all the events (see "additional information")

It works fine, but of course when the number of clients got bigger, the master spreadsheet became slower, and it will only get worse with time.

Here is the formula that i currently use on the master spreadsheet:
`=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(Clients!$K3;"Data!B16:M");IMPORTRANGE(Clients!$K4;"Data!B16:M");IMPORTRANGE(Clients!$K5;"Data!B16:M"); etc etc etc};"Select * where Col1<>''";0)`

Where Clients!$K is the column where we paste the "clients" spreadsheets URL. Of course, we have many more IMPORTRANGE formulas (one per client line)

Thank you VERY MUCH for any help regarding this issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IMPORTRANGE` formula retrieves data from another Sheet by connecting to it, which makes is slower than the others. Therefore, if you want to avoid long waiting times, it’s usually best to minimize the number of these external calls.

Since your Spreadsheet is having quite a lot of data, the best alternative would be to use a script.

**Workaround**:

You could try to use this script and use a trigger which would fire the execution of it to the time mentioned by yourself instead of using the `IMPORTRANGE` which recalculates  the data each 30 minutes.

```
function importRange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("15P9QT4ukwQYnsF7RiHH-e1sSHlK7oyKqhbteiw0_sxQ");
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var urlsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("URLs");
  var urls = urlsSheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues();
  var j=1;
  for (var i=0;i<urls.length;i++) { 
    if (urls[i][0] != "") {
      var valuesToImport = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(urls[i][0]).getSheetByName("ClientData").getRange(1,1,3,2).getValues();
      sourceSheet.getRange(j,1,3,2).setValues(valuesToImport);
      j=j+3;
    }
   }
}
```

The script works by gathering all the urls, checking if the urls are not empty cells and if so, it gets the data wanted and pasting it on the `Data` sheet. Since the data that needs to be pasted into the sheet has **3** rows, in order to be able to execute this operation by choosing the appropriate range without overwriting the cells, the `j` variable has been used.

If you add a trigger on the above function with the following properties, your script will get executed each day during a time frame convenient to you.

To add the trigger you have to click this icon in your Apps Script project and then configure it using the above settings.

**Create trigger**

[image]

**Trigger settings**

[image]

Some tips to avoid the long waiting times:

- **Use closed range references -**
  so for example, instead of using `B16:M`, you could use `B16:M500` (assuming that the data you want ends at `M500`).
- **Use Apps Script**;
- **Migrate to a database -**
  if your Spreadsheet becomes too slow for your liking, you can always try alternatives - like using a database to store your data and perform all the operations necessary.

Moreover, I suggest you check these links since they might be of help:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable);
- [Class Sheet - getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))

Comment: Fantastic, i will try this script right now! 
Also, what do you mean by: 
"you can always try alternatives - like using a database to store your data and perform all the operations necessary."
What is a database, in this case? 
Thank you!

Comment: Hi again, 
So i tested the script. There seems to be an issue: 
In the last line, I replaced by THE_RANGE_WHERE_YOU_IMPORT_THE_VALUES by "A1:Z". I got an error, saying that the number of lines from the data source doesn't correspond with the number of lines in the range. 
So, as a test, i replace A1:Z by A1:A10 (i have 10 lines in my test data) - it works, but it only imports the data from the last URL. Which doesn't surprise me too much; i was actually wondering how the script would paste the data in the sourceSheet. 
Do you know how to solve the issue? 
Thank you again

Comment: @Kev, it's hard to diagnose your issue without seeing the sheets you're using to import data from and to since for me it worked as expected. You might **need** to adjust the ranges to your liking in order to work as expected (I only used the ones provided by you), but it should go through all the links you have. The script pastes the data by using the `setValues()` function.

Comment: Hi Ale13, Thank you very much for your response. I created a drive folder with dummies spreadsheets: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1baADkZgLN8xiBqFUGy14uW5eOTxzcwKu?usp=sharing The script is linked to the "master spreadsheet".

I'm no programmer and unless i made a mistake when replacing values, it seems like there is something missing in the script. Basically something that says "paste each import one below the other" - It seems, as it currently is, that the script pastes the imports one above the other, so only the last import (from the last URL) remains at the end of execution.

Comment: Hello @Kev! Thank you for the spreadsheets provided! I updated my answer and I hope everything works as expected now. Cheers! :)

Comment: Hi @Ale13 ! 
Thank you SO MUCH. This is absolutely perfect. 
People like you make the world a better place ;) 
By any chance, do you program for a living / can you send invoices? If yes, i might have some more scripts requests that I'm willing to pay for (not right now, but i built my information system around google spreadsheets so i often i have script ideas/needs to improve our efficiency - i am obsessed with automatization)